# Angular2 in Javascript, about decorators

Tags: javascript, angular

I've seen in the Angular2 cookbook that we can use the annotations array for providing metadata and to attach to a constructor more than one of the equivalent of a Typescript decorator.

We can also go through the class convenience API with a syntax as below:

```
(function(app){

    var HEROES = app.HEROES;

    app.HeroService = 
        ng.core.Injectable().Class({
            constructor: function(){},
            getHeroes : function(){
                return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
            }
        });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}))
```

**1.** But if I want to attach two decorators? How can I do that?
It seems that this chunk of code works. Is this the right way to proceed if I want two decorators?

```
(function(app){

    var HEROES = app.HEROES;

    app.HeroService = 

        ng.core.Class({
            constructor: function(){},
            getHeroes : function(){
                return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
            }
        });

    app.HeroService = ng.core.Injectable(/*...*/)(app.HeroService);
    app.HeroService = ng.core.Component(/*...*/)(app.HeroService);

})(window.app || (window.app = {}))
```

**2.** Then, what is the difference with the annotation array convenience? What are the most used syntaxes?

Other question, I figured that the code below was working :

```
(function(app){

    var HEROES = app.HEROES;

    app.HeroService = 

        ng.core.Class({
            constructor: function(){},
            getHeroes : function(){
                return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
            }
        });
    //Optional, why ?
    //app.HeroService = ng.core.Injectable()(app.HeroService);

})(window.app || (window.app = {}))
```

**3.** I use this service in many other components of my app. Is the Injectable function optional because I don't provide metadatas? Or am I missing out on an important Angular notion?

**4.** Last question about the *ng.core* namespace what is the difference between this:

```
(function(app){
    var HEROES = app.HEROES;
    app.HeroService = 
        ng.core.Class({
            constructor: function(){},
            getHeroes : function(){
                return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
            }
        });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}))
```

And this:

```
(function(app){

    var HEROES = app.HEROES;

    app.HeroService = function(){
        this.getHeroes = function(){
            return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
        }
    }

})(window.app || (window.app = {}))
```

Comment: use Typescript would save you tons of time

Comment: Thanks, but can I also have constructive responses to my questions ?

Comment: Well, at less not from me. I feel like I have a moral obligation to push others toward a better solution that is how I repay a great open source project.  And I believe by doing so, it will help everyone in the long run. Good luck.